# Removing objects contained in a List<> from another List<>?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an object which is contained within a List<>, I need to remove these from another List<>

e.g.

```
List<MyObject> AllElements = new List<MyObject>();
List<MyObject> SearchResults = new List<MyObject>();
```

... Do something so that SearchResults contains a subset of the objects contained within AllResults

Currently I do this to delete them from the main list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SearchResults.Count; i++) 
    AllElements.Remove(SearchResults[i]);
```

Is there an nicer [linqier!] way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`IEnumerable<T>.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) is your friend (if I'm reading your example correctly):

```
allElements = allElements.Except(searchResults);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Enumerable.Except Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) (from MSDN)

List`<MyObject>` FilteredElements = AllElements.Except(SearchResults).ToList();

Comment: You'll need to tag a `ToList` call on the end if you want the result to be a `List<MyObject>` rather than `IEnumerable<MyObject>`.

Answer (score 3):

The following will give you a 'list' where everything in `SearchResults` was removed.

```
var results = AllElements.Where(i => !SearchResults.Contains(i));
```

You could then do:

```
AllElements = results.AsList();
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using Where/Contains as to simply using Except?

Comment: @Justin, the benefit for me was that I knew about the `Where()` way to do it.  I had no idea you could use `Except()`.  I posted my answer at the same time as your, and I'm gonna leave it up because it is right, and it is good to know other ways to do things.

Comment: (s): There is a semantic difference between them as well. `Except` produces the set difference of the two sequences which means that any duplicates are also removed. For example, if the two sequences are `{ 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4 }` and `{ 3, 4 }` then using `Except` will give you the sequence `{ 1, 2, 5 }` whereas using `Where`/`Contains` will give you `{ 1, 2, 5, 1, 2 }`.